# NullPointerException with findButton() Codename One

Tags: nullpointerexception, codenameone

I'm getting a NullPointerException when I run a very simple piece of code in Codename One, not sure what's the problem. My code is:

```
@Override
protected void beforeMain(Form f) {

    if(zona1.giveNumberofBulbs() != 0){

        int estadoGlobal = zona1.giveGlobalState();

        if(estadoGlobal == 0){
            findIllu2().setText("OFF");
        }
        else if(estadoGlobal == 1){
            findIllu2().setText("ON");
        }
        else{
            findIllu2().setText("...");
        }
    }
    else{
        findIllu1().setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

where Illu1 and Illu2 are Buttons. The exception says java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.findByName(UIBuilder.java:578)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.findIllu2(StateMachineBase.java:530),

appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Super stupid and noob question, I now see. I found the answer few minutes after I posted it, even though it had bugged me for several hours now. I had to give each find function the Form f as argument. Works now!